# Denied Cabal Access to pictures. Now Getting error

Tags: haskell, cabal, macos

Accidentally denied Cabal Access to pictures through a prompt given.  Now, when I try to cabal Init I get this message "User/******/Library/Application Support/MobileSync: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: permission denied (Operation not permitted)"

Ive tried change permissions in the file with CHMOD and reinstalling Cabal without success. Can anyone help me solve this permissions issue?  Im using a MAC.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need to follow these steps. If Cabal isn't listed as an app, try terminal. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-files-and-folders-on-mac-mchld5a35146/mac